# Fill .To with email addresses in named range

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to use a named range to fill my `.To` block in an email.

I prefer not to use active sheet in the code.

```vb
Public Sub cmdEmailODL_Click()
Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim EItem As Object
Dim ODLEmail As Range
ODLEmail = Sheets.ODLEmail.Range("ODL_Emails")

With EItem
    .To = ODLEmail
    .Subject = "Overdue items"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Dim'd the wb, ws and the rngODLEmail then Set them and called rngODLEmail in my .To block.

```vb
Public Sub cmdEmailODL_Click()
Dim EApp As Object
Dim EItem As Object
Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Eitem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("ODLEmail")

Dim rngODLEmail As Range
Set rngODLEmail = ws.Range("A2:A2")

With EItem
    .To = rngODLEmail
    .Subject = "Overdue items"
```